# Why can't the browser successfully use the given cookie?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I was making a website using Apache Tomcat.

At first, I used an IP adress as both the webpages' address and the apis' address, there was no problem with the setting of Cookies. When I was signing in, `http://A.B.C.D:8080/api/signin` set a cookie like `sessdata=XXX`, and requests sent by `http://A.B.C.D:8080/default.js` could get login status properly.

But today when I changed the webpages' address into `https://www.example.top/` (using cloudflare and vercel) and the apis' address into `https://api.example.top/` (using nat), I found out that the sign in function couldn't work properly. It worked like that:

`http://www.example.com/signin.js` sent a request to `https://api.example.top/api/signin`,

`https://api.example.top/api/signin` responded with a ```set-cookie`` header:

`sessdata=XXX;`

I have also tried:

`sessdata=XXX; Domain=example.top; Path=/`

`sessdata=XXX; Domain=api.example.top; Path=/`

`sessdata=XXX; Domain=www.example.top; Path=/`

`sessdata=XXX; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Tue, 08-Aug-2090 08:08:00 GMT; Domain=example.top; Path=/`

Although it did set the cookies, the other JS scripts don't bring the cookies when they send requests to the api, and I can't find the cookie on my browser either.

I have also manually added the cookie at `api.example.top`, it worked when I send requests to the API directly, but it didn't work when using JS scripts.

Here are my codes.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        User verifying = UserGetter.getUserByMail(new String(request.getParameter("mail").getBytes("ISO8859-1"),"UTF-8"));
        if(verifying.uid==-1) {
            out.println("{\"code\":1}");
        } else if(verifying.pword_md5.contentEquals(stringToMD5(new String(request.getParameter("password").getBytes("ISO8859-1"),"UTF-8")))) {
            Cookie session = new Cookie("sessdata",SessionBind.newBinding(verifying.uid));
            session.setDomain("example.top");
            session.setPath("/");
            session.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            session.setSecure(false);
            response.addCookie(session);
            out.println("{\"code\":0}");
        } else {
            out.println("{\"code\":2}");
        }
    }
```

```
function signin(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        switch(JSON.parse(this.responseText).code){
            case 0:
            location.href = "https://www.example.top/signinSuccess.html"
            break;
            case 1:
            alert("This email doesn't exist")
            break;
            case 2:
            alert("Incorrect email or password")
        }
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://api.example.top/api/signin", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xhttp.send("password="+document.getElementById("i2").value+"&mail="+document.getElementById("i1").value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by no means a front-end developer nor a vercel expert. But you might just need to ensure the `withCredentials` flag is set on your XHR request object:

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Description:

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a boolean value that
> indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be
> made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS
> client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on
> same-site requests.

Comment: Thanx, after setting `withCredentials`, I've got a CORS error. Then I modified my api headers as `access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.example.top`, It worked properly.